# ListIterator for a one way linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, singly-linked-list, listiterator

So I've implemented a single-linked `LinkedList` which extends generic type `AbstractSequentialList`. I'm overriding the `listIterator` method, so have made a new class that implements generic type `ListIterator` which gets instantiated in the listIterator method of my linked list class. I have a few questions:

- The `listIterator` method that I override needs an int parameter, what is the purpose of this? Do I go to that index of the list and pass that node through to the instantiated `ListIterator`?
- Does the index always start at 0 for the `ListIterator`, even if I'm starting to iterate from a node in the middle of the list?
- In the `ListIterator` class how do I write the `hasPrevious` and `Previous` method if the list is singly linked?

Comment: 3. Very slowly.

Comment: 3.  You can't, efficiently.  You will need to make it doubly linked to make that work well.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is the position to start at (refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html#listIterator(int))). `HasPrevious` you need to check the cursor !=0 (see [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr)). For previous, you will need to use you list implementation's get(I) method as given [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ListItr).

Does this help?